# Can I have more than one describe per test spec?

Tags: tests

I started to writing tests a few time ago and faced a non-mature question: can I have more than one `describe` per unit test file?

If so, in what circumstances this will happen?

Because so far, I'm describing a/an module/object like this:

**tests/User-spec.js**

```
describe ('A user', function () {
  it ('should add a "to do" into the list', function () {
    var user = new User;
    var list = new List({ name: 'Home' });

    user.add('Buying some groceries.').to(list);

    expect(list.items[0]).to.be('Buying some groceries.');
  });
});
```

In other words, each file of my tests describes an object—there's no space for another `describe`.

I know there are a few good/bad practices about tests, and technically I can add more than one describe per spec—I just do not know wether this is the "*best*" way to go or even good.

Can you describe to me some scenarios where more than one `describe` could be within the same spec file? Or even wether my `describe` is or isn't wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the Jasmine testing framework since that's the only one I know of with describe() and it().

**Yes, it's totally fine.** The only thing that describe() does is designate a piece of text to be the "header" that describes a group of tests. The Jasmine intro page even says

> The describe function is for grouping related specs

and Jasmine supports *nested* describes() too.

So the real question here is **what is the most intuitive and readable way to group your tests**. If it's a small class with not very much to test, one header is probably fine.

```
Class A
    Foo
    Bar
    Foo with non-ASCII characters
    Bar with MAX_INT
```

If this is it, using more than one describe() is probably overkill.

After a few years of feature creep it may warrant a bit more.

```
Class A

    Basic Calls
        Foo
        Bar
        Baz
        Shazam

    Edge Cases/Regression Tests
        Foo with non-ASCII characters
        Bar with MAX_INT
        Shazam after Foo(Bar(42*-6))
        Baz before m_count is initialized

    Compatibility Shims/Polyfills
        Foo without generators
        Bar without getPrototypeOf()
```

Do whatever makes the output more readable for your team.

Comment: BTW `jest` also has `it()` and `describe()` functions: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describename-fn